# Get specific button ID and div ID inside a loop

Tags: jquery

Please anyone have an idea on doing this logic?? I want to make specific id of button and div for whenever I click the specific post the button 'x'(which is the del button for post) will appear. I can't run properly in jQuery so please help. Any ideas will highlyappreciated. Thanks :) here's the code:

```
var r = 0;
while(r < 2000){
r++;
$("#groups").on('click', '#post_tbl'+r, function(){

    $("#delpost1"+r).toggle("fast");

});}
```

and for div and button that is looped:

```
<?php

$c = 0;
while($c < 2000)
{
$c++;
echo "<div id='post_tbl$c' >";
echo "POST"; // I don't include the whole code for looping post from database for simplicity of my question 
echo "<button id='delpost$c' style='display: none;' >x</button>";
echo "</div>";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$c = 0;
while($c < 2000)
{
$c++;
echo "<div id='post_tbl$c' class='postclass' >";
echo "POST"; // I don't include the whole code for looping post from database for     simplicity of my question 
echo "<button class='togglebutton' id='delpost$c' style='display: none;' >x</button>";
echo "</div>";

}

?>
```

and in jquery

```
$(document).on('click','.postclass',function(){
  $(this).find('.togglebutton').toggle('fast');
});
```

in this case u dont need to use any ids

anyways if you are trying to use same type of elements again ,try using a class instead of id unless it is compulsorly needed

Comment: I Have question sir Bhadra. If I'm not mistaken, the full jQuery code might look like this??

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click','.postclass',function(){
      $(this).find('.togglebutton').toggle('fast');
    });

});

Comment: yes ,that is it. you dont need to bind the click to every id, if u are using class like this

Answer (score 0):

It makes more sense to me to put the id of the div inside it's own location instead of appending it to the end of each id in the loop.

For example: in the PHP, include the id in a hidden variable

```
<div class="post_tbl">
     <input class="post_id" type="hidden" value='<?php echo $c; ?>' />
     <button class="delete">X</button>
</div>
```

And in the jquery, when you click the X - look for the closest ID.

```
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.post_id').val();
    // do stuff with id
});
```

Comment: looks like I completely misread your question - but what I wrote up might still prove useful.  good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response sir. I get the point. :) But I want to correct my question. Replace the code .on('click') in jquery to .on('mouseenter') . Well thanks a lot sir. God bless :D